# "Xcode cannot run using the selected device"

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment

"No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination."

Until recently I had no problem deploying an app from Xcode onto my iPhone 6.  But suddenly it stopped working.

I can still deploy onto my iPad mini.

Only difference is that the iPhone 6 is on latest iOS - 8.3, and iPad mini is still on 8.2.

I double checked and the iPhone 6 UDID is still registered.

The app is deploying for iOS 8.0 - BELOW the phone's iOS.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems, your bundle identifier is not recognized. Check:

1) Click on XCode project -> Project Target -> Info

2) Check ''Bundle identifier'' for validation

If Bundle Identifier is not your, change to your valid.

If Bundle Identifier is your, try refresh him in developer.apple.com and reinstall him in your Mac.

**BUT**

Great solution is:

1) Open XCode -> Preferences

2) Click 'Accounts'

3) Click '+'  at left colum

4) Enter your Apple login and password

5) Click XCode Project -> Project Target -> General

6) In 'Team' select your Apple ID

7) Click on 'Fix issue'

At this case, your bundle, your certificates from developer.apple.com will refresh from XCode by this great 'Fix issue' button.

**UPD**

If you're still have a problem, try delete all old provisions by this steps:

1) Open in Finder: Users/{username}/Library/MobileDevice/Provision Profiles/

2) Select all mobile provision files and Move to trash

3) Open your XCode project

4) Just run your project in registered device

Now XCode will download new provision file from itunesconnect.apple.com, if your Apple ID is already registered into XCode->Preferences->Accounts

Comment: Ok I'll look at that now, thank you.  But if my 'Bundle Identifier' was wrong, it wouldn't work on my iPad Mini either - right?

Comment: This has not solved my problem.  I went into Apple Developer account.  Created a new Identifier under my iOS Developer profile.  Added this to Xcode - still doesn't work.

Comment: @BenB Are you tried to click on 'Fix issue' button on XCode in General tab?

Comment: It doesn't give me that option.  But as I mentioned previously - if there was an issue with the bundle identifier - wouldn't it prevent me from launching on my iPad mini also?

Comment: @BenB if your bundle identifier is wrong, you can't install your app in any device

Comment: @BenB i'm updated answer, check him at bottom. Maybe issue in your old mobile provision files

Comment: Hi @CReaTuS - I did as you suggested and deleted the provision profiles.  When I tried to rerun the project, it came up with the same error message.  It did though give me the option to 'fix issue', which I did, but on trying to run again - same error message! Any other ideas?! Thanks!

Comment: Hi @BenB - Check your XCode Target -> Team. Try set here your Apple ID. If this will not help, at this moments, i'm trying start from begin. Try download any other demo project(e.g. Facebook demos) and put him your bundle identifier. If this demo will run at successfully, then your bundle is OK, and try search problem in other configurations. If not, then your bundle is wrong. If wrong, you can reinstall your XCode, recreate all your Apple app ids, bundle identifiers, reregister your devices and recreate all certificates.